# Filter/merge based on closest value

Tags: r, filter, merge, dplyr

I'd like to filter the `time` when a `turbidity` value is closest to **0.7** from my data frame **`df`**. I then want to use that time to `filter` the nearest times per group for two other `parameters`.

---

**Example**

*Raw Data*

```
print(df)

   sample   time parameter measurement
1   apple  0.000 turbidity       0.153
2   apple 13.805 turbidity       0.654
3   apple 16.586 turbidity       0.724 * Closest to 0.7
4   apple 25.354 turbidity       0.821
5   apple  0.000   glucose      34.100
6   apple 13.548   glucose      29.500
7   apple 17.254   glucose      17.300 ** Closest time when turbidity measurement is closest to 0.7
8   apple 24.893   glucose       4.100
9   apple  0.000  muconate       0.000
10  apple 13.412  muconate       3.500
11  apple 17.647  muconate       9.600 ** Closest time when turbidity measurement is closest to 0.7
12  apple 25.841  muconate      13.400
13 orange  0.000 turbidity       0.116
14 orange 12.655 turbidity       0.689 * Closest to 0.7
15 orange 14.214 turbidity       0.715
16 orange 32.687 turbidity       0.899
17 orange  0.000   glucose      35.600
18 orange 12.021   glucose      28.700 ** Closest time when turbidity measurement is closest to 0.7
19 orange 15.687   glucose      16.400
20 orange 33.641   glucose       3.700
21 orange  0.000  muconate       0.000
22 orange 13.365  muconate       3.200 ** Closest time when turbidity measurement is closest to 0.7
23 orange 18.259  muconate       8.500
24 orange 35.697  muconate      14.100
```

---

**Desired Output**

Filter rows that have a `turbidity` value closest to **0.7**, but keep them grouped by `sample` based on the nearest `time` value.

```
  sample    time parameter measurement
1 apple     16.6 turbidity       0.724
2 apple   17.254   glucose      17.300
3 apple   17.647  muconate       9.600
4 orange    12.7 turbidity       0.689
5 orange  12.021   glucose      28.700
6 orange  13.365  muconate       3.200
```

---

**Failed Attempt**

```
df %>% group_by(sample) %>%
    filter(parameter == "turbidity") %>%
    slice(which.min(abs(measurement - 0.7))) 

  sample  time parameter measurement
1 apple   16.6 turbidity       0.724
2 orange  12.7 turbidity       0.689
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# get index of turbidity rows with measurement closest to 0.7
turb_Is <- 
  df[parameter == 'turbidity', .I[which.min(abs(measurement - 0.7))], sample]$V1
# join df with subset identified by turb_Is to identify turbidity time
df[df[turb_Is], on = .(sample), turbtime := i.time]

# select rows with lowest difference from turbtime in each (sample, parameter) group
df[df[, .I[which.min(abs(time - turbtime))], .(sample, parameter)]$V1, -'turbtime']
#    sample   time parameter measurement
# 1:  apple 16.586 turbidity       0.724
# 2:  apple 17.254   glucose      17.300
# 3:  apple 17.647  muconate       9.600
# 4: orange 12.655 turbidity       0.689
# 5: orange 12.021   glucose      28.700
# 6: orange 13.365  muconate       3.200
```

Same idea with dplyr

```
df %>% 
  group_by(sample) %>%
  filter(parameter == "turbidity") %>%
  slice(which.min(abs(measurement - 0.7))) %>% 
  select(sample, time) %>% 
  right_join(df, by = 'sample') %>% 
  group_by(sample, parameter) %>% 
  slice(which.min(abs(time.x - time.y))) %>% 
  select(-time.x) %>% 
  rename_at('time.y', ~ 'time')

# # A tibble: 6 x 4
# # Groups:   sample, parameter [6]
#   sample  time parameter measurement
#   <chr>  <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
# 1 apple   17.3 glucose        17.3  
# 2 apple   17.6 muconate        9.6  
# 3 apple   16.6 turbidity       0.724
# 4 orange  12.0 glucose        28.7  
# 5 orange  13.4 muconate        3.2  
# 6 orange  12.7 turbidity       0.689
```

Simpler dplyr method (same output)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(sample) %>%
  group_modify(~{
    turb <- 
      filter(., parameter == 'turbidity') %>% 
        slice(which.min(abs(measurement - 0.7)))
    group_by(., parameter) %>% 
      slice(which.min(abs(time - turb$time)))
  })
```

Data used

```
structure(list(sample = c("apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", 
"apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", 
"apple", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", 
"orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange"), 
    time = c(0, 13.805, 16.586, 25.354, 0, 13.548, 17.254, 24.893, 
    0, 13.412, 17.647, 25.841, 0, 12.655, 14.214, 32.687, 0, 
    12.021, 15.687, 33.641, 0, 13.365, 18.259, 35.697), parameter = c("turbidity", 
    "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "glucose", "glucose", 
    "glucose", "glucose", "muconate", "muconate", "muconate", 
    "muconate", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", "turbidity", 
    "glucose", "glucose", "glucose", "glucose", "muconate", "muconate", 
    "muconate", "muconate"), measurement = c(0.153, 0.654, 0.724, 
    0.821, 34.1, 29.5, 17.3, 4.1, 0, 3.5, 9.6, 13.4, 0.116, 0.689, 
    0.715, 0.899, 35.6, 28.7, 16.4, 3.7, 0, 3.2, 8.5, 14.1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = "data.frame", index = structure(integer(0), "`__parameter`" = c(5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L)))
```

Comment: Works great and maintains the `dplyr` piping! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Or using base R:

```
df_list <- split(df, df$sample)
turbidity_ref_pt <- 0.7
do.call(rbind, lapply(df_list, function(x){
  turb_row<- x[x$parameter=='turbidity', ][which.min(abs(x$measurement[x$parameter=='turbidity'] - turbidity_ref_pt)), ]
  gluc_row <- x[x$parameter=='glucose', ][which.min(abs(x$time[x$parameter=='glucose']-turb_row$time)), ]
  muco_row <- x[x$parameter=='muconate', ][which.min(abs(x$time[x$parameter=='muconate']-turb_row$time)), ]
  rbind(turb_row, gluc_row, muco_row)
}))

#          sample   time parameter measurement
#apple.3    apple 16.586 turbidity       0.724
#apple.7    apple 17.254   glucose      17.300
#apple.11   apple 17.647  muconate       9.600
#orange.14 orange 12.655 turbidity       0.689
#orange.18 orange 12.021   glucose      28.700
#orange.22 orange 13.365  muconate       3.200
```